# Lookup and get date of lower range for in between date in Excel Formula

Tags: excel, date, formula

Dataset 1:

| ID | Date | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5/10/2022 | Apple |
| 1 | 1/10/2022 | Orange |
| 1 | 10/10/2022 | Strawberry |
| 2 | 1/10/2022 | Kiwi |

Dataset 2:

| ID | Date Modified | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30/9/2022 |  |
| 1 | 4/10/2022 |  |
| 1 | 9/10/2022 |  |
| 1 | 11/10/2022 |  |
| 2 | 9/9/2022 |  |
| 2 | 10/10/2022 |  |

For the same ID, if there are multiple rows of the same ID eg. ID 1, there are 3 dates: 1/10/2022, 5/10/2022, 10/10/2022

If the date modified date in dataset 2 is less than the minimum date (1/10/2022) then it will retrieve the item Orange from the minimum date (1/10/2022).

If the date modified date (4/10/2022) in dataset 2 is in between the date range (1/10/2022 and 5/10/2022) of the same ID 1, then it will retrieve the item of the lower date range which is Orange from 1/10/2022.

If the date modified date (11/10/2022) is larger than the maximum date (10/10/2022) of the same ID1, then get the item Strawberry from the date (10/10/2022).

Result in Dataset 2:

| ID | Date Modified | Item: |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30/9/2022 | Orange |
| 1 | 4/10/2022 | Orange |
| 1 | 9/10/2022 | Apple |
| 1 | 11/10/2022 | Strawberry |
| 2 | 9/9/2022 | Kiwi |
| 2 | 10/10/2022 | Kiwi |

Thank you.

Comment: You explain for 3 condition, minimum, between, maximum. How excel will know which condition will be applied to which date?

Comment: @Harun24hr you have any ideas on the work around? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just follow the logic you presented based on min, max dates for a given **id** column value. Put the following formula in `G2` cell:

```
=LET(in, A2:C5, A, TAKE(in,,1), B, INDEX(in,,2), C, TAKE(in,,-1),
 lk, E2:F7, MAP(TAKE(lk,,1), DROP(lk,,1), LAMBDA(id,date,
 LET(f, FILTER(B, A=id),refDate, XLOOKUP(date,f,f,MIN(f),-1), 
 TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(C, (A=id) * (B=refDate)))))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

It is nothing than to put in excel terms the logic, we use `MAP` to iterate over the lookup values (`lk)`, filter the dates from the input data (`in`) for a given `id`. We use `XLOOKUP` with additional optional input parameters to satisfy the dates requirements to return the reference date (`refDate`):

```
=XLOOKUP(lookup_value, lookup_array, return_array, [if_not_found], [match_mode])
```

where

- `match_mode=-1`: Exact match. If none found, return the next smaller item
- `if_not_found=min(f)`: If the lookup date (`date`) is lower, then it returns the minimum.

Finally `FILTER` finds the corresponding **item** value for a given `refDate` and `id`.

I added a `TEXTJOIN` call, just in case there are more than one **item** value that satisfies the condition, if it doesn't make sense, because only one item will be returned, then it can be removed.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for helping. For ID 1, because 10/9 is in between 10/5 and 10/10, that's why should take 10/5 which is apple

Comment: Oh, then is not between min and max per `id` and instead find  the closest interval and take the minimum. Correct? Please confirm. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks David for your help! :) can check how to translate this into power query custom column formula in power bi?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I am not familiar with Power Query, maybe you can formulate another question asking for specific solution under those tools.